# is `python3` always installed with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shebang

I usually start all my scripts with the shebang line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

However our production server has Python 2 as the default `python`, while all of our new scripts and programs are being built under Python 3. To help keep people from accidentally running the script with the default Python 2, I am considering switching all my shebangs from now on to this;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

On our server, `python3` indeed points to Python 3, and our basic scripts will run correctly on it. However I am not clear if this is something specific to our installation, or if `python3` is *always* available if Python 3 is installed?

I know this probably will not help a user who runs `$ python myscript.py` when the default Python is loaded, but its better than nothing and is clear enough in letting a user who inspects the script realize they are using the wrong Python version. Though now I also realize that, with Python being on version 3.8, a Python 4 is imminent... at the same time, I am not sure I am ready to embed code in every single script to check if Python >= 3 is loaded...

Comment: Python 4 is nowhere near imminent.

Comment: `python3` is a much more reliable way to get Python 3 than just `python`. Just `python` is much more likely (at time of writing) to get you Python 2, even on a machine where Python 3 is also installed.

Comment: "Though now I also realize that, with Python being on version 3.8, a Python 4 is imminent" Why so? After 3.8 and 3.9, the next versions will probably be 3.10, 3.11 etc., until there will be another incompatible cut, which will bring us Python 4.0.

Comment: @glglgl you are correct... I forgot about semantic versioning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a safe bet.

[PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) recommends Python 3 be available under the binary name `python3` and most Linux distributions follow this recommendation. In fact, this is the *only* name under which Python 3 has been available in most distributions (the only outlier being Arch Linux, but even that also provides a `python3` binary), and plans to make the ‘plain’ `python` binary also refer to Python 3 have only been made quite recently. The article [‘Revisiting PEP 394’](https://lwn.net/Articles/780737/) on LWN.net has more details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a python 3 version only install's `python3` if there is already another version of python installed, no matter if it is a python 2 or python 3 version, because the standard `python` command would then not work properly for the new version of python.

But please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: It depends on the OS. Windows is inconsistent (on my Windows system `python` is Python 2, `py` is Python 3, `python3` and `py3` doesn't exist). Any Linux current LTS distro you always have a `python3`. If you do `ll /usr/bin | grep python` and have multiple python interpreters installed you see it is just a bunch of links `->`.